# Is there a way to specify the specific interactions you are interested in an anova using R while modeling within subjects errror?

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run a single model and am interested in all main effects and some interactions. However, I have so many variables that trying to run it all in one model is resulting in four and five way interactions that I have no theoretical predictions about and would be meaningless to interpret. I am predicting DV from:

Observed_1

Observed_2

Observed_3

condition

outcome

I am trying to examine the main effects of everything and the interactions between Observed_1, Observed_2, and Observed_3 as well as the interactions between condition and outcome but I don't need the four and five way interactions that result from throwing all of this into the model. I have tried

```r
model_aov <- aov_car(DV ~ 
    (Observed_1*Observed_2*Observed_3) + 
    (condition*outcome) + 
    Error(Subject/(condition*outcome)), 
    data=dataFrame,  factorize=FALSE, 
    observed=c("Observed_1", "Observed_2", 
    "Observed_3"),  na.rm=TRUE)
```

but this still returns all possible interactions despite enclosing the sets of variables in parentheses.

I also tried specifying an object using terms to run this:

```r
model_terms <- terms(dataFrame$DV ~ 
   dataFrame$Observed_1 + dataFrame$Observed_2 +
   dataFrame$Observed_3 + dataFrame$condition + 
   dataFrame$outcome +  
   dataFrame$Observed_1*dataFrame$Observed_2 + 
   dataFrame$Observed_1 * dataFrame$Observed_3 +
   dataFrame$Observed_2 * dataFrame$Observed_3 +
   dataFrame$condition*dataFrame$outcome, 
   keep.order = TRUE)
modelTerms_aov <- lm(model_terms, 
   data = dataFrame)
anova(modelTerms_aov)
```

and this works to specify only the interactions I am interested in, but I am not able to specify the error term using this method which is a problem.

Comment: Your notation is unusual because you have *outcome* as a predictor. How were subjects randomized to *condition* and *outcome*?

Comment: outcome refers to whether they won or lost a trial (all of which was pre-programmed). I'm measuring the intensity of a shock they delivered to an opponent so outcome is to determine whether they shocked more intensely following losing versus winning trials. Each participant also experienced both conditions of the study, and there were winning and losing trials in each condition.

Comment: So *outcome* is a setting you controlled experimentally (though the participants didn't know it)? In any case, the documentation for *afex::aov_car* states "The within-subject factors do fully interact with all between-subject factors and covariates".